# "fatal: unable to auto-detect email address" in DOCKER

Tags: git, docker, ubuntu-20.04, nvidia-docker

My docker run is failing because git complains that I didnt set a user config which I never needed for my older images.

```
From git.mysite.com:user/project
 * branch            dev -> FETCH_HEAD
*** Please tell me who you are.
Run
   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
   git config --global user.name "Your Name"
to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'root@V_2_compute1.(none)')
```

I have two Dockerfiles which are quite similar but behave differently.

The first one with [nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:20.02-tf1-py3](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tensorflow-release-notes/rel_20-02.html#rel_20-02) as its source and the second one with [nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:20.12-tf2-py3](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tensorflow-release-notes/rel_20-12.html#rel_20-12).
The first is a **Ubuntu 18.04** and the second one **Ubuntu 20.04**. When inspecting the containers, they have different git versions (**2.17.1** vs **2.25.1**) but I'm not sure if this is the problem.

Here are the two Dockerfile (simplified):

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental

FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:20.02-tf1-py3 as intermediate

ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY

RUN apt-get update \
&& export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
&& apt-get install -y git \
&& mkdir /srv/username \
&& cd /srv/username
RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan git.mysite.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
ADD "https://www.random.org/cgi-bin/randbyte?nbytes=10&format=h" skipcache
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone -b master git@git.mysite.com:user/project.git /srv/username/project
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/srv/username/project"
CMD /usr/sbin/service ssh restart && cd /srv/username/project && git pull origin feature-branch && git checkout feature-branch \
&& /srv/username/project/script.py
```

The problematic one:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental

FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:20.12-tf2-py3 as intermediate

ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY

RUN apt-get update \
&& export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
&& apt-get install -y git \
&& mkdir /srv/username \
&& cd /srv/username
RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan git.mysite.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
ADD "https://www.random.org/cgi-bin/randbyte?nbytes=10&format=h" skipcache
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone -b master git@git.mysite.com:user/project.git /srv/username/project
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/srv/username/project"
CMD /usr/sbin/service ssh restart && cd /srv/username/project && git pull origin dev && git checkout dev \
&& /srv/username/project/script.py
```

Why do I now have to config a user in the latest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find why the error occured but I found a solution to remove it.
Instead of cloning master then pulling the branch, I directly clone the branch I want to use.

The cloning line is now :

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone --single-branch -b dev git@git.mysite.com:user/project.git /srv/username/project
```

Notice the use of `-b dev` with `--single-branch` to clone only the specified branch.

I am still not sure why the error occured in one case but not in the other. It might be because `--mount=type=ssh` can't be used in last `CMD` but then it should have failed in both case.